# Рассчитать время выполнения участка кода внутри метода

Tags: java

Хочу посчитать время выполнения части кода внутри метода (не весь метод).

Я не хочу использовать такую конструкцию

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Я также пробовал Guava, но он по-прежнему дает тот же результат, что и предыдущий, потому что при выполнении несколько раз подряд этот метод в режиме выполнения дает разные результаты (результат становится намного меньше, чем в первый раз, а мне это не подходит).

Я решил попробовать JMH. На основании оф доков я могу измерить время выполнения всего метода. Но мне нужно измерить только его часть (например, запрос к базе данных и все, не более того: mysqlTemplate.queryForList (selectQuery);).

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> selectMySql() {

    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList();
    String selectQuery = prop.getMYSQL_SELECT();

    try {
        list = mysqlTemplate.queryForList(selectQuery);

        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            throw new QueryUpdateException("Data not found for update!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;
}
```

Может у кого-то есть идеи на этот счет ? 
Или кто может предложить альтернативные варианты использования ?
Спасибо.

Comment: а в чем, собственно, вопрос? вас смущает,что время разное? так оно ибудет разное, тем более для запросов к бд. вспомните,как минимум, про кеширование...

Comment: @Дмитрий т.е. такого момент мне не избежать, что при частом обновлении страницы (выполнении метода который дергает запрос в базу) время его выполнения будет колебаться ?

Comment: @Дмитрий вы предлагает оставить реализацию с помощью Guava или все таки сделать это через аспекты или JMH или может написать свой BeanPostProcessor, который будет вычислять время выполнения метода, помеченного кастомной аннотацией ?

Comment: Я не понимаю вашей цели, поэтому не могу ответить на Ваш вопрос. Зачем вам измерять время? это такое логирование? с другой стороны важно, какие технологии уже есть на проекте? например, вы используете спринг?

Comment: @Дмитрий да, простите, не сказал. Использую SpringBoot. Мне надо просто вывести пользователю на фронт информацию о длительности времени выполнения запроса в базу. В проекте используются разные базы. Другими словами некая статистика